# SharePoint 2013 | Users lose connection to website when accessing outside organization network

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have an intranet website for organization staff only. Users keep losing connection to website when accessing outside organization network as the browser stops loading the page and the message shown is: "could not open the page because the server stopped responding". The page is loaded after refreshing for two to three times.
The website is working fine while using the organization network. Windows and Forms Authentications are enabled.
What can cause the lost connections problem to the server? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.